# How to change URL while getting response page in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2, message, double-submit-prevention

I am doing registration using Struts and Hibernate here and I am facing a problem like when I run my project I get

```
localhost/ProjectName/registration.jsp
```

when I submit the data, data successfully saved in database, after saving data in database I am looking for  `registration.jsp` as response page but that time URL will be

```
localhost/ProjectName/actionName.action
```

this would create a problem like if I refresh page the last added record will be added again

**JSP Form:**

```
<s:form action="register">
</s:form>
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```
<action name="register" class="-----------">
    <result name="success">registration.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: @Andrea Ligios before knowing the things please do not mark it as duplicate because many persons have  good  knowledge of doing work some of the peoples they may not have good communication to explain

Comment: "Before knowing the things" ? You're asking for a way to prevent double submissions, that is PRG (Post-Redirect-Get). You're using Struts2. The answer (to the question your is a duplicate of) explains exactly how to achieve PRG with Struts2. Why should I not consider this a duplicate ?

Comment: Yes it is PRG i have tried that way but  before redirecting i should show message like Registration Successful how can i do this

Comment: By Showing a message in the G page, the page you call with GET, the landing page ? No matter If it is the same page that started the original request or a different page, just add an actionMessage and show it in the page if present

Comment: @jancy pradeep messages are in the property that you should create. Don't mess up messages from validation and errors with your own messages.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow [PRG pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27874233/573032) mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31483491/573032) answer.

Create a *new* action `registrationSuccess` that will return your JSP page after redirect action result.

```xml
<action name="register" class="-----------">
 <interceptor-ref name="store"> 
    <param name="operationMode">STORE</param> 
  </interceptor-ref> 
  <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" /> 
  <result name="success" type="redirectAction">registrationSuccess</result>
</action>

<action name="registrationSuccess">
  <interceptor-ref name="store"> 
    <param name="operationMode">RETRIEVE</param> 
  </interceptor-ref> 
  <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
  <result name="success">registration.jsp</result>
</action>
```

---

You can use [`store` Interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/message-store-interceptor.html) to store action messages/errors in HTTP session. The action class should implement `ValidationAware`.

The `store` interceptor works between two actions, one of them store the messages, another retrieve them.

> An interceptor to store a `ValidationAware` action's messages / errors
> and field errors into HTTP Session, such that it will be retrievable
> at a later stage. This allows the action's message / errors and field
> errors to be available longer that just the particular HTTP request.
>
> If no session exists, nothing will be stored and can be retrieved
> later. In other terms, the application is responsible to open the
> session.
>
> In the `STORE` mode, the interceptor will store the `ValidationAware`
> action's message / errors and field errors into HTTP session.
>
> In the `RETRIEVE` mode, the interceptor will retrieve the stored
> action's message / errors and field errors and put them back into the
> `ValidationAware` action.
>
> In the `AUTOMATIC` mode, the interceptor will always retrieve the stored
> action's message / errors and field errors and put them back into the
> `ValidationAware` action, and after Action execution, if the Result is
> an instance of `ServletRedirectResult`, the action's message / errors
> and field errors into automatically be stored in the HTTP session..

---

Comment: I tried this way its correct but before redirecting i should show message like Registration Successful  how can i do this

Comment: Add action messages to the action context.

Comment: you can also show the message in the session, whatever you prefer.

Comment: How can you to propgate the message in your answer like

Comment: <action name="submitApplication" ....>
    <interceptor-ref name="store">
        <param name="operationMode">STORE</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
    <result name="input" type="redirectAction">applicationFailed</result>
    <result type="dispatcher">applicationSuccess.jsp</result>
</action>
 
<action name="applicationFailed" ....>
    <interceptor-ref name="store">
        <param name="operationMode">RETRIEVE</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <result>applicationFailed.jsp</result>
</action>

Comment: message store interceptor uses a session.